# USB Tuner TV : Eye TV Go not Recognized

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, tv-tuner

My tuner TV "Eye Tv Go" is not recognized ( Ubuntu 14.04, kernel `4.2.0-42-generic` )

`$ tail -f /var/log/syslog`

```
usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 12
usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fd9, idProduct=0058
usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 2-1.1: Product: EyeTV Go
usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Elgato
usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 141204000686
mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 13: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1"
mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 13 was not an MTP device
```

The Chipset is it9135.
There are firmware files in `/usr/lib/firmware` : `dvb-usb-it9135-01.fw` and `dvb-usb-it9135-02.fw`

How use it ? or fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

use this patch and this should work

---

drivers/media/usb/dvb-usb-v2/af9035.c | 2 ++
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)

diff --git a/drivers/media/usb/dvb-usb-v2/af9035.c b/drivers/media/usb/dvb-usb-v2/af9035.c
index 021e4d3..804df72 100644
--- a/drivers/media/usb/dvb-usb-v2/af9035.c
+++ b/drivers/media/usb/dvb-usb-v2/af9035.c
@@ -1529,6 +1529,8 @@ static const struct usb_device_id af9035_id_table[] = {
        &af9035_props, "Leadtek WinFast DTV Dongle Dual", NULL) },
    { DVB_USB_DEVICE(USB_VID_HAUPPAUGE, 0xf900,
        &af9035_props, "Hauppauge WinTV-MiniStick 2", NULL) },
+   { DVB_USB_DEVICE(USB_VID_ELGATO, 0x0058,
+       &af9035_props, "Elgato EyeTV Go", NULL) },
    { }
 };

### MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, af9035_id_table);

1.9.0

Comment: Patch of what? What is this?

Answer (score 0):

I searched high and low for how to get the Elgato EyeTV Go working on a Raspberry Pi and found your question and the response. I'm no expert, but got it going--thanks.

My experience is as follows. I grabbed the source code, then edited the following files by adding new entries as suggested in the answer. Once edited, I recompiled the kernel. On reboot tvheadend picked up the tuner, but had identified it as "Afatech AF9033 (DVB-T)" and it has been working flawlessly. There is possibly a tidier way to do it, but I'm happy with this.

File 1:
/linux/drivers/media/usb/dvb-usb-v2/af9035.c
Approx Line 2143 add
{DVB_USB_DEVICE(USB_VID_ELGATO, USB_PID_ELGATO_EYETV_GO, &af9035_props, "Elgato EyeTV Go", NULL)},

File 2:
/linux/include/media/dvb-usb-ids.h
Approx Line 45 existing definition (no change)
#define USB_VID_ELGATO 0x0fd9

Approx Line 220 add
#define USB_PID_ELGATO_EYETV_GO 0x0058